# request_spot_instance API is not accepting user data in file format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am using AWS API to create a spot instance. When I try to give user data in a file format , I get an error

> "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RequestSpotInstances operation: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data

```
session = boto3.Session()
client = session.client('ec2', region_name = 'us-west-2')

response = client.request_spot_instances(
    InstanceCount=1,
    LaunchSpecification={

        'ImageId': 'ami-012345',
        'InstanceType': 't2.medium',
        'Placement': {'AvailabilityZone': 'us-west-2a'},
        'SecurityGroupIds': ['sg-012345'],
        'SubnetId': 'subnet-012345',
    'UserData': 'file://my_script0.txt'
    },
    SpotPrice='0.0139',
    Type='persistent',
    InstanceInterruptionBehavior = 'stop'

)
```

As per the AWS documentation, if we wanted to pass the user data as a file, we can do that by preceding the file name with "file://". 
But it seems that this API is expecting the entire file content to be base64 encoded first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html, the base64 is only for API calls and not the CLI.

So when I pass base64 encoded data of my file , then the API works correctly.

```
file  = open("my_script0.txt", 'r')
encoded_data = base64.encodestring(file.read())
```